# Scrapyd error - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'module_name'

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

This is my `setup.py` generated by running `scrapyd-deploy`

My project is named `crawler` and exists in the `crawler` directory

```
# Automatically created by: scrapyd-deploy

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name         = 'project',
    version      = '1.0',
    packages     = find_packages(),
    entry_points = {'crawler': ['settings = crawler.settings']},
)
```

I get this error when i `cd` into `crawler` and run `scrapyd-deploy`

```
Packing version 1440426986
Deploying to project "crawler" in http://localhost:6800/addversion.json
Server response (200):
{"status": "error", "message": "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'module_name'", "node_name": "mybox"}
```

This is the stacktrace from scrapyd

```
2015-08-24 20:06:26+0530 [HTTPChannel,28,127.0.0.1] Unhandled Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/tejesh/projects/billionleads/python/python2.7-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/web/http.py", line 1755, in allContentReceived
        req.requestReceived(command, path, version)
      File "/home/tejesh/projects/billionleads/python/python2.7-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/web/http.py", line 823, in requestReceived
        self.process()
      File "/home/tejesh/projects/billionleads/python/python2.7-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/web/server.py", line 189, in process
        self.render(resrc)
      File "/home/tejesh/projects/billionleads/python/python2.7-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/web/server.py", line 238, in render
        body = resrc.render(self)
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "/home/tejesh/projects/billionleads/python/python2.7-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd/webservice.py", line 17, in render
        return JsonResource.render(self, txrequest)
      File "/home/tejesh/projects/billionleads/python/python2.7-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd/utils.py", line 19, in render
        r = resource.Resource.render(self, txrequest)
      File "/home/tejesh/projects/billionleads/python/python2.7-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/web/resource.py", line 250, in render
        return m(request)
      File "/home/tejesh/projects/billionleads/python/python2.7-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd/webservice.py", line 68, in render_POST
        spiders = get_spider_list(project)
      File "/home/tejesh/projects/billionleads/python/python2.7-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapyd/utils.py", line 114, in get_spider_list
        raise RuntimeError(msg.splitlines()[-1])
    exceptions.RuntimeError: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'module_name'
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: 'crawler' mean is you project name

Answer (score 0):

Change value in `entry_points` to `'scrapy'` instead of `'crawler'`

```
setup(
    name         = 'project',
    version      = '1.0',
    packages     = find_packages(),
    entry_points = {'scrapy': ['settings = crawler.settings']},
)
```

Comment: No module named 'crawler'